# How to compare 2 passwords in BCrypt in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bcrypt

I'm using the gem "bcrypt". It's a Rack app. Once I've created a password hash and stored it in my db,

```
    # register a user

    plain_pass = get_input_from_user
    pass_hash = BCrypt::Password.create(params["pass"])

    # store in db
    # ......
```

**how can I then compare to the *plain* that comes from a user?**

```
    email = get_user_email
    usr = User.first(email: params["email"])

    plain_pass = params["pass"]
    pass_hash = ?????
    if usr.pass_hash == pass_hash
      # ok, all good
```

The issue is that `Password.create` creates a new password each time, even with the same input:

```
irb(main):038:0> BCrypt::Password.create("aaa")
=> "$2a$10$CCWMcREb5mP2ldFshb4qiua.VK2ABHXCtDSzj2WwYf/KsZQjoDGoO"

irb(main):039:0> BCrypt::Password.create("aaa")
=> "$2a$10$w9rAu9FmLZ/jQ7IQmXutW.nh272ucS0PsIrMYUMBrDQpt4U70wOqa"
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're using `==`. Your example shows assignment (`=`).

Bcrypt::Password overrides the `==` method, which is how you should compare passwords:

```
crypted_password = Bcrypt::Password.create("foobarbaz")
# save crypted_password to db

# Presumably later on when your user returns
BCrypt::Password.new(crypted_password) == "foobarbaz" # => true
```

Comment: how does that help me?

Comment: you didn't understand my question

Comment: True, you'll need to also use `BCrypt::Password.new`

Comment: For anyone wanting a bit more detail on this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44778735/328817 might be helpful.